# How to set on change as a default on page load jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a on change method for a select box of my project. On selecting particular option it is basically showing and hiding a div which is perfectly working fine. Now, my problem is when first time page is loading this show and hide not working for first default section of form. Can I make this onchange function also working when page load first time.

```
$('.contact-form').on('change', (e) => {
    var selectedId = $(e.currentTarget).val();
    var listofforms = $("#discount").data("display-for").split(",");
    if (listofforms.indexOf(selectedId) !== -1) {
        $("#discount").collapse('show');
    }
    else {
        $("#discount").collapse('hide');
    }
});
```

Comment: But on page load `$(e.currentTarget).val()` will always be empty, what should happen in that case?

Comment: it is not empty. it is filled by MVC object.

Comment: Also, do you have multiple elements with class `.contact-form` on the page or just one?

Comment: @Html.DropDownList("myFormID", Model.discountlist, new { @class = $"form-control contact-form" })

Comment: I am using above for entry in select values (options) in Select

Comment: On page load what does `console.log( $('.contact-form').val() )` returns? can you check that once.

Comment: is it possible can I make my on change trigger on page load

Answer (score 2):

Here you go with a solution

```js
function changeMethod(selectedId) {
  var listofforms = $("#discount").data("display-for").split(",");
  if (listofforms.indexOf(selectedId) !== -1) {
    $("#discount").collapse('show');
  }
  else {
    $("#discount").collapse('hide');
  }
}

changeMethod($('.contact-form').val())

$('.contact-form').on('change', (e) => {
  changeMethod($(e.currentTarget).val());
});
```

You need to move your code outside the change event, so I have kept your existing code within a method `changeMethod`.

Then call the method from to places

1. From you change event method
2. OnLoad of the JS file

Comment: nice decoupling of the `changeMethod`

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible can I make my on change trigger on page load

Yes, you will just need to change your on change event from `e.currentTarget` to `this` as on page load `e.currentTarget` will be null, but `this` always points to the current element like:

```
$('.contact-form').on('change', function() {
  var selectedId = $(this).val();
  // Your other logic here
});
```

and to trigger this change event on page load, simply add `.change()` at last like:

```
$('.contact-form').on('change', function() {
  var selectedId = $(this).val();
  // Your other logic here
}).change();   //<---- here
```